# Iptables и перенаправление трафика

Tags: iptables

Здравствуйте товарищи умные люди. Есть такое правило:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 0.0.0.0/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp ! --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.1.5
```

Как можно заменить порт 22 на порт 22 + диапазон портов 1100-1200? Пробовал подставить 22,1100:1200, не получилось.

Сразу второй вопрос. Посложнее. Как через iptables перенаправить UDP трафик с x.x.x.x:N на y.y.y.y:N, при чем N - это определенный одинаковый порт из диапазона 1100-1200, неужели для каждого порта писать отдельную строчку?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 1):

нужно подгрузить модуль multiport

```bash
    ... -m multiport --dports 22,1100:1200 ...
```